# Sort dict by multiple keys and with int and None data in python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, types

so I have a dict :

```
marker_dict[experiment_id] = {'SM0012AQ': { 'chromosome' : 1, 'linkageGroup':8, 'positionCm' : 45,'qualityStatus' : 'A' },
 'SM0075AQ': { 'chromosome' : 1, 'linkageGroup': 7, 'positionCm' : ,'qualityStatus' : 'A' }, 
'SM0078BQ': { 'chromosome' : 3, 'linkageGroup': 78, 'positionCm' : 7,'qualityStatus' : 'B' },
'SM0079PQ': { 'chromosome' : 4, 'linkageGroup': , 'positionCm' : 80,'qualityStatus' : 'B' },
'SM0080BQ': { 'chromosome' : , 'linkageGroup': 78, 'positionCm' : 447,'qualityStatus' : 'T' }}
```

I want to sort my dict on 'i.chromosome', 'i.linkageGroup' and 'i.positionCm'

What I am doing :

```
marker_list = sorted(marker_dict[experiment_id].values(), key=lambda i: (i.chromosome, i.linkageGroup, i.positionCm))
```

And i got :

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Nonetype' and 'int'
```

In python 2, they were doing :

```
markerList=sorted(markerDic.values(), key=operator.attrgetter('chromosome','linkageGroup','positionCm'))
```

Could you help me please, I am lost !

Comment: What you could do is in the lambda function have a "ternary operator" and set that to either 0, a large number (positive or negative), e.g. `i.chromosome if i.chromosome is not None else 0`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I edited it, None before ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```py
t = {'SM0012AQ': { 'chromosome' : 1, 'linkageGroup':8, 'positionCm' : 45,'qualityStatus' : 'A' },
    'SM0075AQ': { 'chromosome' : 1, 'linkageGroup': 7, 'positionCm' : None ,'qualityStatus' : 'A' },
    'SM0078BQ': { 'chromosome' : 3, 'linkageGroup': 78, 'positionCm' : 7,'qualityStatus' : 'B' },
    'SM0079PQ': { 'chromosome' : 4, 'linkageGroup': None, 'positionCm' : 80,'qualityStatus' : 'B' },
    'SM0080BQ': { 'chromosome' : None, 'linkageGroup': 78, 'positionCm' : 447,'qualityStatus' : 'T' }}
```

and the requirement that `None`s are for `int`, you can solve it using

```py
dict(sorted(t.items(), key=lambda i: (i[1]['chromosome'] if i[1]['chromosome'] is not None else -1, i[1]['linkageGroup'] if i[1]['linkageGroup'] is not None else -1 , i[1]['positionCm'] if i[1]['positionCm'] is not None else -1)))
```

where I've made the assumption that the numbers you have are 0 or positive. If you can also have negatives you need to change the -1 to a very large negative number.

The result:

```
{'SM0080BQ': {'chromosome': None,
  'linkageGroup': 78,
  'positionCm': 447,
  'qualityStatus': 'T'},
 'SM0075AQ': {'chromosome': 1,
  'linkageGroup': 7,
  'positionCm': None,
  'qualityStatus': 'A'},
 'SM0012AQ': {'chromosome': 1,
  'linkageGroup': 8,
  'positionCm': 45,
  'qualityStatus': 'A'},
 'SM0078BQ': {'chromosome': 3,
  'linkageGroup': 78,
  'positionCm': 7,
  'qualityStatus': 'B'},
 'SM0079PQ': {'chromosome': 4,
  'linkageGroup': None,
  'positionCm': 80,
  'qualityStatus': 'B'}}
```

Comment: *"If you can also have negatives you need to change the -1 to a very large negative number."* - Nah, no need to do that. Safer alternative is to include a bool before the value in the key tuple.

Comment: It works thank you ! But with t.values and not t.items

Answer (score 0):

If all your values are greater than zero, you could use your original approach with `or 0` to convert `None` values to zeroes and get then first in the sort order:

```
sorted(marker_dict[experiment_id].values(), 
       key=lambda i: (i.chromosome or 0, i.linkageGroup or 0, i.positionCm or 0))
```

Other wise you could write a small function to handle None values by converting the numbers to a tuple that prefixes the value with True/False depending on it not being None.

```
def None1st(*numbers): return [(n is not None,n or 0) for n in numbers]

sorted(marker_dict[experiment_id].values(), 
       key=lambda i: None1st(i.chromosome, i.linkageGroup, i.positionCm))
```